# Check if AVAudioPlayer is playing

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I've been trying to check if the AVAudioPlayer is currently playing, but when I try to do it in anyway it crashes.

I'm using stop button to stop the audio but when there is no audio playing it crashes.

How is it possible to check it in my `stopaudio` function ?

First I defined :

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

I have stop button :

```
func stopaudio(sender: AnyObject){
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

I tried to check like this :

```
if audioPlayer.playing{
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

I am using the following code to play the audio :

```
var soundURL: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("9", ofType: "m4a")!)!
var error:NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: It should work try println(true) inside the conditional

Comment: try checking if audioPlayer != nil first

Comment: @Christian , it prints like this "(lldb) " and shows that `audioPlayer.stop()` without handling , and when i handle it , it indicates this line : `if audioPlayer.playing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was because the AVAudioPlayer hasn't been initialized yet, so what i did to fix it is to initialize it and then stop it.

```
var soundURL: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("013", ofType: "m4a")!)!
var error:NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: &error)
audioPlayer.stop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a function in the ViewController class:

```
func tryAudio() {
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        } catch {
            //handle errors
        } 

    }
```

call tryAudio() to initialize the player before player.stop()

Comment: I have a class on NSObject just to handle the app sounds. The app was crashing when the app restarted with the sounds enabled, but the player not yet initialize. My solution was overriding its init method so now it is good to go.

Comment: This also inits the AVAudioPlayer but in a safe way