# How can I start and stop audio using a single button?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a sleep timer app that allows the use of 9 different sounds to help you fall asleep. The last thing I need is to be able to play the sounds when I tap a button, and to stop that same sound when I press it again. I've tried to do it with this:

```
@IBAction func heavyThunderBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    heavyThunderBtn.isSelected = true
    toggleButton(button: sender, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_selected"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_unselected"))
    numberOfPresses += 1


    if numberOfPresses % 2 == 0 || numberOfPresses == 1 && numberOfPresses != 2 {
    do {
        rainAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thunder", ofType: "mp3")!))
        rainAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        rainAudioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
    else {
        rainAudioPlayer.stop()

    }
}
```

But it allows me to press the button, it plays the audio and the button changes to the color I've chosen indicating it's on. Then when I press it again, the audio restarts and keeps playing, then when I press it again, it stops but the button is blue again indicating that it's on. So this is what I've changed it to, but I get a crash every time I press the button to play audio. The error I get is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0 x 48)"

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RainSoundsViewController: UIViewController {

var rainAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var numberOfPresses = 0
var tappedAgain: Bool! = false

var heavyThunderOffImage = UIImage()

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var heavyThunderBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var lightRainBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var rainOnRoofBtn: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    heavyThunderOffImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_unselected")

    heavyThunderBtn.isSelected = false

    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    backgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true


}

@IBAction func dismissPopup(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func heavyThunderBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    heavyThunderBtn.isSelected = true
    toggleButton(button: sender, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_selected"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_unselected"))
    numberOfPresses += 1


    if rainAudioPlayer.isPlaying {

    do {
        rainAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thunder", ofType: "mp3")!))
        rainAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        rainAudioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
    else {
        rainAudioPlayer.stop()

    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Line 51, if rainAudioPlayer.isPlaying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if AVAudioPlayer is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30302640/check-if-avaudioplayer-is-playing)

Answer (score 1):

The most important flaw in your code, exists in this line:

```
var rainAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

The initializer `init()` is not well-defined for `AVAudioPlayer` and the result is unpredictable. In fact, this initializer creates a completely useless object.

And `rainAudioPlayer` becomes non-Optional with the declaration above, so you cannot check if it is properly initialized or not.

**Make it Optional.** Do not give it a useless initial value.

```
var rainAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
```

With this change, some other parts of your code needs to be fixed. For example, the condition of the `if`-statement would be:

```
if rainAudioPlayer?.isPlaying ?? false {
```

Or:

```
if let player = rainAudioPlayer, player.isPlaying {
```

---

Full code with some other recommendations:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RainSoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var rainAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? //### You should not instantiate a useless instance.
    var numberOfPresses = 0
    var tappedAgain: Bool = false //<- You have no reason to make this Implicitly Unwrapped Optional.

    var heavyThunderOffImage: UIImage! //<- Do you really need this?

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var heavyThunderBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var lightRainBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var rainOnRoofBtn: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        heavyThunderOffImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_selected")

        heavyThunderBtn.isSelected = false

        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        backgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    @IBAction func dismissPopup(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func heavyThunderBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        heavyThunderBtn.isSelected = true
        toggleButton(button: sender, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_selected"), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "thunderstorm_unselected"))
        numberOfPresses += 1

        if rainAudioPlayer?.isPlaying ?? false { //### `rainAudioPlayer` is now Optional.

            do {
                rainAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "thunder", withExtension: "mp3")!) //<- You can use `url(forResource:withExtension:)`.
                //`play()` internally calls `prepareToPlay()`, you have no need to call it here.
                rainAudioPlayer?.play()
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else {
            rainAudioPlayer?.stop() //<- Here, `rainAudioPlayer` is NOT playing, do you need to stop it?
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

I haven't checked if other parts of this code work as you expect, but would not cause **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** no more.

Comment: Made all changes you recommended, but now the audio no longer plays no matter how many times I press my button.

Comment: @CameronL, Have you read my comment in the code? Your original code is trying to start playing when the player is playing, trying to stop playing when the player is NOT playing. I do not understand how you want to utilize `numberOfPresses`. So, it's you who need to fix that sort of basic logic.

Comment: Okay, I read back over it, is the else statement where I need to stop the player/pause the audio?

Comment: @CameronL, As I wrote, it is not clear enough what you expect with your changed code. Just to test my code, replace the codes in the `true`-block and the `else`-block. But the behavior may not be what you expect. If you can update your question and clarify _what happens when_ more precisely, I believe I can be some help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing with the numberOfPresses logic. Seems super confusing.

Simplify your logic this way. (Note: this is in objective-C)

```
static boolean soundPlaying=false; //declare a static variable

//now in your button you turn on/off the sound this way
- (IBAction) heavyThunderBtnPressed
{
   if (soundPlaying == false)
   {
     //initialize your AVAudioPlayer play sound. add code here
     // ....
     soundPlaying = true; //set this to true as you are playing the sound
   }
   else
   {
     //sound was already playing so stop it. add code here
     // ....
     soundPlaying = false; //set this to false as you have stopped the sound
   }

}
```

Comment: It gives me the same result of pressing it makes it look like it's been turned off (button is gray) but plays, then when I press it again (it looks like it's on) but then it stops after. Switching the states.